# build a regex password 6 letters, 2 digits, and 1 punctuation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a regex that matches for the following

1. 6 letters
2. digits
3. 1 punctuation

my special characters from my backend to support js `special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;,'\[\]]"`

and a minimum of a length of at least 8 or longer.

my password javascript client-side is the following, but however, how can I build a regex with the following data?

```
if (password === '') {
    addErrorTo('password', data['message']['password1']);
} else if(password){
    addErrorTo('password', data['message']['password1']);
}else {
    removeErrorFrom('password');
}
```

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/are-password-complexity-rules-counterproductive; https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: sure, but I am not forcing them to be specific . they are free to use their own password with some security in mind , but how can I build that regex?

Comment: If you aren't forcing them to be specific, then why would u need the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if `password.length >= 6`

Then I would do it like this:

1. Set up a `letterCount`, `numCount`, `puncCount`
2. Loop through the string and earch time you encounter a letter, increase the `letterCount` (`letterCount++`), each time you encounter a number increase `numCount` and so on.
3. Then validate your password using the counter variables.

This is a good approach because you can tell the user what went wrong. For example, if they only entered 1 number, you can see that from the `numCount` and tell them specifically that they need at least 2 numbers. You can't do that with just one Regex.

EDIT: Heres the code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
  const currentChar = password[i];
  if (checkIfLetter(currentChar)) {
    letterCount++;
  }

  if (checkIfNumber(currentChar)) {
    numCount++;
  }
  
  if (checkIfPunc(currentChar)) {
    puncCount++;
  }
}
```

Then check if the `numCount > 2` and so on. I would write the actual regexs but I don't know them myself. It should be pretty easy, just return `true` if the provided char is a letter for the first function, a number for the second one and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple REGEXes to check for each requirement.

```
let containsAtLeastSixChars = /(\w[^\w]*){6}/.test(password);
let containsAtLeastTwoDigits = /(\d[^\d]*){2}/.test(password);
let containsAtLeastOnePunct = new RegExp(special_characters).test(password);
let isAtLeast8Digits = password.length >= 8;
```

Then if any of these booleans are false, you can inform the user. A well designed site will show which one is wrong, and display what the user needs to fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*[0-9]).{2}(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6}(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]).{1}$
```

6Letters, 2digits, and 1 special character.

Comment: how can I know the 2 digits , and 6 letters plus one punctuation?